# ms access 2003 .mdb cannot view the table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I'm using ms access 2007. I save the  database contain table in 2003 format.  If i open a file, i saw four table. But three table are able to open. one table is unable to open and occur a message unrecognized database format.Please help me. It's very important one. How to recover that table.

Comment: you can try to compress and repair your db

Comment: If i'm repair, that table is automatically removed.

Comment: Does Access give you an error message when opening the problem table fails?

Comment: I just open my database. If i open that particular table, then occur the error message

Answer (score 0):

If compress and repair your db cannot restore your table, I think that the only thing you can try is to create a new empty access db and import your four tables from your corrupted db.

Comment: Its not working. Occur a message , "Microsoft Access can't find the database".

Comment: If i directly open that table , occur a message," unrecognized database format"